# Can one use PiFace for A/D conversion?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi

the PiFace is [advertised](http://pifacedigital.wordpress.com/) as the shield "connecting the Raspberry Pi to the real world" and they claim that this includes things like temperature sensors. I know how to read the temperature using an AVR microcontroller and the A/D converter, but I cannot see that such a converter is present on the PiFace. Am I missing something (I'm not a native english speaker, it may actually be the case that I don't understand what I've found). The inputs I found seem to be just capable of being switched on and off, and the examples I've seen are also restricted in that sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small data sheet for the PiFace [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1682890.pdf) on Farnell. There's a schematic linked to from [this post](http://pifacedigital.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/kernel-driver-delays-and-new-interface-board/).

It has digital inputs and outputs only, no ADC. Most sites advertise it using 'PiFace Digital I/O Expansion' as its full name, with no mention of analogue.

You don't need to use PiFace IO expansion to read temperature sensors, the gpio will do, as in [this adafruit tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing) on reading a DS18B20.